# Extract image from RMarkDown HTML

Tags: floats, html, rmarkdown

I often generate reports using RMarkDown. These include images based on analyses which are encoded in the knitted HTML file in [URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) format.

The following RMarkDown can be knitted to such a file.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
date: "9/30/2021"
output: html_document
---

## Test

```{r Figure3}
plot(pressure)
```
````

The resulting knitted HMTL file includes a part like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw ..." width="672" />
```

I would like my LaTeX file to reference directly to this image, embedded in the HTML file. Something like:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{MyRMarkDown.html#Figure3}
\caption{Figure from RMarkDown HTML file}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: "reference to this image"? Not clear if you are searching a hyperlink to the image in the HTML document, or show that image in the PDF. In the second case, why not a knitted  Rmarkdown to  PDF, or a Seawe to PDF,  running  the same R chunk? or why not save the  image as pdf in the working directory during the HTML compilation, or  keep the source image (in `figure-html/Figure3-1.png`) with `keep_md: true`,  so the PDF or the PNG can be used latter by any other document, instead of getting in the mess of extract an image codified as text data in html?

Comment: Well, the knitted RMarkDown contains the analyses including the plots as output. The LaTeX will be an article which describes some of the analyses and includes some of the plots, but is quite separate from the RMarkdown. So knitting to PDF is not really an option, the article needs to be in LaTex. As for saving the image, that means manually duplicating a plot which already happily lives inside my HMTL file. Not ideal.

Comment: What duplicate? What living plot? You have only text inside a text file that a browser use to produce an image in the poor PNG format, but `\includegraphics` need an already existing  image file.  On the other hand, knitting your Rmarkdown to PDF is already knitting to a LaTeX article and with   `keep_tex: yes`  you can maintain the LaTeX source. It is also possible run R chunks within  LaTeX code (Sweave file  with .Rnw extension) so knitting is *for sure* an option, that moreover will produce a scalable vectorial image (pdf file), not the pixelated image of the html file.

Comment: I am not asking for workarounds, I am asking for what's in my question. If it's not possible, then it's not possible.

Comment: Sort answer: Not possible. Long answer: Not possible without extracting the inline base64 character streams, with the browser or some any other tool,  to a standalone  PNG, which does not make more sense, but less, than saving it before (in PDF format) when generated from R code.